# The Profile Picture is not visible on the Top Bar

Tags: reactjs, mern

This a blog page using the Fullstack MERN Application. And it should show the uploaded Profile pic of the user when the particular user is Logged in on the Top bar. But in my case it is not showing up. Same thing is happening for the About me Image. But the difference is that the Image in the About me component is visible when the user is logging out and then logging in again.
The code for the Top Bar component is :

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import "./topbar.css";

export default function TopBar() {
  const { user, dispatch } = useContext(Context);
  const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images"
  // console.log(PF+user.profilePic)

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  };
  return (
    <div className="top">
      <div className="topLeft">
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-pinterest-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
      </div>
      <div className="topCenter">
        <ul className="topList">
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/">
              HOME
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/">
              ABOUT
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/">
              CONTACT
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/write">
              WRITE
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topListItem" onClick={handleLogout}>
            {user && "LOGOUT"}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="topRight">
        {user  ? (
          <Link to="/settings">
            <img className="topImg" src={PF + user.profilePic} alt="" />
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <ul className="topList">
            <li className="topListItem">
              <Link className="link" to="/login">
                LOGIN
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="topListItem">
              <Link className="link" to="/register">
                REGISTER
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )}
        <i className="topSearchIcon fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

COde For the Sidebar:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./sidebar.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../context/Context";

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useContext(Context);
  const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images/";

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCats = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/categories");
      setCats(res.data);
    };
    getCats();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebarItem">
        <span className="sidebarTitle">ABOUT ME</span>
        {user && <img
          src={PF + user.profilePic}
          alt=""
        />}
        
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate qui
          necessitatibus nostrum illum reprehenderit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebarItem">
        <span className="sidebarTitle">CATEGORIES</span>
        <ul className="sidebarList">
          {cats.map((c) => (
            <Link to={`/?cat=${c.name}`} className="link">
            <li className="sidebarListItem">{c.name}</li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebarItem">
        <span className="sidebarTitle">FOLLOW US</span>
        <div className="sidebarSocial">
          <i className="sidebarIcon fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
          <i className="sidebarIcon fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
          <i className="sidebarIcon fab fa-pinterest-square"></i>
          <i className="sidebarIcon fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[The Image of the Top Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jojyj.png)

Also when the user is uploading the image a random no. is added in front of the file in the Data base which
I have manually remove to load the image to the server. As it is not able to read it like:
[The random numbers in frond of the name of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDzg7.png)

I tried some Stack over flow answer like:[TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814894/typeerror-cannot-read-property-image-of-null)
This helped me with the Side bar problem but not fully.